# Highcharts - Is there a way to Magnify the complete chart DIV to full page and then reverse.?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts 4.2.5. 
I have 2 charts on my page with 50% , 50% width. I have a requirement where, i would like to provide the user with a magnifier icon on top of each chart, to allow him to maximize the chart to 100% width to view.

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: I have two user experience questions: 1) What would happen to the other chart when the user decides to magnify one? 2) How would you want the user to reduce the size back to 50% to view both charts again?

Comment: You can use Chart.setSize() in your case for chaning the width/height of your chart: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setSize

Comment: @MikeZavarello the chart which i want to maximize will behave like a modal box, and will popup at the center of the page. On the click of cancel button , the chart will go back to its original width.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński i can set the size of the chart, but i want the outer div to manage the positioning and not the chart . Should'nt the chart resize it according to the outer div size ?

Comment: It depends on how you are changing the outer div, you have chart.reflow() method made in cases when chart will not resize: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.reflow You can also see this HC forum topic, it may help you with your issue: http://forum.highcharts.com/post122890.html?hilit=chart%20popup#p122890